60s/70s Sci-Fi movie
I recall a small scene (near the end likely) of a group of young people (kids to 20s/30s) that are living in a bunker. They are questioning and yet waiting for the sun to rise. 
The planet has been in darkness for so long that the idea of a sunrise is skeptical. But it rises and everyone welcomes it with awe and surprise.
I know this is at least a 70s film if not older, because it was a late night movie that I only saw the end of because I woke up before it ended. I saw it between '78-82, which is why I give it a 70s to possibly 60s timeframe.
The feeling that I recall was that darkness lasted lifetimes or at least decades and was why a sunrise was not believed.

I was thinking it might have been Nightfall, but the plot is actually backwards to yours and it is way newer. Nightfall was originally conceived by Isaac Asimov. Hope someone can find it for you.

Napolean do u have a FB or some other means to communicate directly? I see you edit  and comment, and have questions but this isn't the place (except, I don't see what your edit on this was excepting perhaps spelling or punctuation.)

You can use the chat room to do that. Use the link or click on the StackExchange twiddle in the top bar on the left to find a link.

@JeffMahaney: If you're click ever curious. click on the "edited ... ago" link and you can compare the different versions and see what was changed. As you are asking people about a particular movie, Napoleon added the "identify-this-movie" tag.

@JeffMahaney I just added the identify-this-movie tag. Other than that, you can use the @-syntax (which is also helped by the framework with auto-completion) in your comment to address any previous commenter (or an editor of the post for that matter). With this syntax the user adressed is automatically notified of the reply. And comments are indeed the perfect place for clarifications about other comments and edits so don't hesitate to ask them if they pertain to the respective post they're under.


Could be "All Summer in a Day (1982)".
From the Learning Corporation of America's catalog:

Set on a planet where the sun shines for just a few minutes every
  nine years, this is a classic tale of forgiveness. 



Margot, a child who yearns for her sunny past on earth, is locked in a
  storage room during the sun’s rare appearance. The other children,
  overwhelmed by the event have forgotten and left her there...

~ Movie screenshots from digplanet and Hacking Christianity
Read more about it here, here and here. Watch the film to confirm.
